# Can't locate EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

Or at least I can't figure out how to locate the error.  I've read a ton of stuff but every time I go into my Product scheme and turn on Guard Malloc my program won't run.

The line of code that is giving me the problem is this... It happens on the NSString *str = ... line

```
- (void) setVolumeCompletionDate: (NSString *)volumeID: (double)completionDate
{
    sqlite3_stmt *pStmt;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Volumes SET GoalDate = %d WHERE VolumeID = '%@'", completionDate, volumeID];

    //more stuff
}
```

If I hardcode the completionDate value (1350129600) on that line, the code works just fine, so it seems from everything I've read that the memory of completionDate is getting stepped on somewhere, or something bad is happening.  My project is set up for ARC.

I think part of my problem is I don't even know where to go to begin to resolve this problem.  I don't even know what to search for.  All of the posts I've read about tracking it down with some Malloc tool don't make sense because I can't get that to run.

I would like to be able to figure this out.  Maybe I need more, and complete steps, for debugging and tracing through things.  Many of the answers I've read seem like they are written for people who know everything, because so much is left out of the answer, or so much is assumed about the person asking the question.  If there is a better place for me to go to ask my question, please point me in that direction.

Thanks a lot.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`completionDate` is a `double`, so use %f instead of %d.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: I believe %lf would be more precise.

Comment: Thank you so much.  There is so much I don't know, and every minute I spend teaching myself how to program only exposes my shortcomings even more.  But, I am determined.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Joel: I think %f vs. %lf is applicable to printf/scanf, but NSString seems to use %f always so I'm not sure %lf is correct in this case.  Refer to the link I added above in my answer.

Comment: @cbranch: Thanks for that link.  I happened upon it once, but couldn't find it again.  It is now bookmarked.  Thanks.